# Contar total de subitems en datatables.net

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, datatable, table

Estoy usando [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) y tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito contar cuantos items hay en cada periodo.

Por ejemplo para para contar cuantos periodos distinto hay

```
var total = rows.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
  if ( last !== group ) {
    count = count + 1;
    last = group;
  }
});
```

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Hacer algo similar a lo anterior, pero contando la cantidad de items para un mismo periodo.

Cómo puedo hacerlo, sugerencias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un objeto donde acumules los totales por grupo.

```
let totales = {};
rows.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'}).data().each((group, i) => {
    if(!totales.hasOwnProperty(group)) {
        // No se ha creado el contador para este grupo
        totales[group] = 0;
    }
    // Incrementar contador
    totales[group] ++;
});
console.log(totales);
```

Suponiendo que los grupos son 2020 y 2021, con la imagen que colocaste va a resultar algo como:

```
{
    "2020": 2,
    "2021": 1
}
```

Después puedes recorrerlos usando [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys), que devuelve un arreglo con las propiedades del objeto:

```js
let totales = {
    "2020": 2,
    "2021": 1
};

Object.keys(totales).forEach(key => console.log(`${key} = ${totales[key]}`));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo probaré y te comentaré.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias @Triby